# How to move an image in background along with a moving object?

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I have a background sketch of building. Now i want to move that horizontally along with a cartoon.

Basically i have cartoon that moves inside the building from this end to another. I want to zoom in to the cartoon and also want that as the cartoon moves the background also moves so if gives a motion effect.

The White lane is where the cartoon moves from one end to another. i want to zoom into image and the cartoon at their position and want the BG to move along with cartoon. move here means **reval**  as it moves forward

This is my background[image: red]